# Magento 2 lazy load for product price and add to cart button

Tags: magento2, lazyload

I want to load the web page in step by step, for example when i login as customer to the homepage, the web will load the structure (like product name first) and as time flow the price will loaded, product image loaded, and add to cart button will appear (depend on product stock).
I could do that for the image with lazy loader extension that i got from store, but how can i do it for the other (price and getting stock for button)?

Answer (score 0):

By design lazy loading is meant for external assets. Since the actual text of the products is mostly loaded at once the only way I see this happening is if you implement some kind of faux-lazy-load by hiding all the elements and then, for example, using jquery have them all appear in the order that you want.

Alternatively you can rebuild the whole page using Knockout or a different library and load everything from the server using Ajax but it's a lot of extra compared to the above solution.